# How can I install composer for php 5.2?

Tags: php, composer-php

I would like to download legacy version of composer for php 5.2.

How do I install composer for php 5.2?

Comment: Latest version so far is 1.0.0-alpha8. It doesn't look as if there's a legacy version.

Comment: You can't: Composer required PHP 5.3. End of story. Also, please note that PHP 5.2 has been end-of-life for more than three years now. It has numerous known security bugs that will never be fixed. If you're still using PHP 5.2 then your system is insecure: you need to urgently consider upgrading.

Comment: don't think this is off topic (maybe i'm wrong?) becuase it relates to `php 5.2` more than the tool because given composers stance as the `php dependency manager` at the moment, I feel it refers more to `php's dependency manager` rather than a `...tool, library or favorite off-site resource`.. so up voting question.

As an answer - delete the `/vendor/composer` folder and the `/vendor/autoload.php` file. Then try `require`ing the folders/files left. If they have `namespacing` or `__DIR__` then whole package is useless on  `php 5.2`.

Comment: Not off-topic at all.

Answer (score 9):

You can't, because [Composer requires PHP 5.3.2 or later](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements):

> #### System requirements
>
> Composer requires PHP 5.3.2+ to run. A few sensitive php settings and compile flags are also required, but the installer will warn you about any incompatibilities.
>
> To install packages from sources instead of simple zip archives, you will need git, svn or hg depending on how the package is version-controlled.
>
> Composer is multi-platform and we strive to make it run equally well on Windows, Linux and OSX.

Comment: Solution problem in old developer PHP for version 5.2.x view info PHP 5.2 https://bitbucket.org/xrstf/composer-php52

Comment: From that project's README: "Please do not use this, if you can avoid it. It's a horrible hack, often breaks and is extremely tied to Composer's interna. This package was originally developed in 2012, when PHP 5.2 was much more common on cheap webhosts." I _strongly_ recommend upgrading to a supported version of PHP instead of using one that's been end-of-life since 2013.